# how to control plot display in spyder?

Tags: python

I have a for loop (20 loops) where plot.show() is designed to show a plot each of 20 loops. Before I used other IDE, so each loop will show a plot and then I have to manually close the plot before showing next plot. Now running in spyder, all the 20 plots are shown one by one automatically. How can I force spyder to manual close each plot before showing next plot?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Which version of spyder are you using? Spyder 4 should show plots in the "Plots" section above the console in the top-right quadrant of the screen.

Comment: Thanks WovVes. I am using Spyder 4. Yes they were there before. I clicked the 3 stars button of remove all the plots. After that, it never show again even I restarted spyder. Any setting I need to change? Thanks

Comment: Once you remove the plots you will have to re-run them to get them to show again in the Plots section. You should be able to scroll through all of them during that time. If you really want them to open one by one then close, you will need to save the file, have python manage the open of the image, wait for the close before moving forward, and then continue the loop. OpenCV can help with that. The editor has options for the graphics, under `IPython console > Graphics`, but not what you are looking for. It also just might be worth saving each of your plots if you want them to persist anyway.

Comment: Thanks Wolves2. I appreciate your help. yes I did re-run it and no plots are shown in the plot section. all the plots are popup automatically it is strange. I might make some change on run setting? Any idea?  Also how opencv help? Thanks